# New line in hosts file

Tags: vpn, windows-8.1, cisco

Not sure if this should be on here or something like `ServerFault`.

I frequently use my `hosts` file to redirect my Apache virtual hosts to `localhost` so I can test them on my own machine.

My school, NJIT, uses Cisco AnyConnect for its VPN. It's an older version, that doesn't seem to have support for my operating system (Windows 8.1) (but somehow it works), just so you know how old  it is. (I have given up asking myself why they wait so long to change things.)

AnyConnect recently added a new line at the bottom of my `hosts` file that I have never seen before (I have been using this VPN on & off for about 1-2 years):

```
128.235.249.35  asa2.njit.edu ###Cisco AnyConnect VPN client modified this file. Please do not modify contents until this comment is removed.
```

When I enter the IP address 128.235.249.35 or the URL asa2.njit.edu into my browser, the webpage that shows up looks like a login page. Indeed, it looks like the login page that shows up whenever I use AnyConnect as a separate program. I suppose that means the VPN travels through that URL on its way to & from the host computer.

What is this line for? I haven't recently updated Windows 8.1 or AnyConnect, & I don't believe they have. Also, if I know what I am doing, is it OK to remove the line? I assume AnyConnect will keep adding it, so how could I remove it for good?

Comment: is this IP your VPN ASA IP ? 128.235.249.35?? I open it and there is Any Connect VPN interface

Comment: That is what that line in a `hosts` file means, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Cisco AnyConnect changes your hosts file every time it connects, and resets it to a file called hosts.ac.

The addition of that one line to the hosts file would allow you to still connect to your VPN terminator even if DNS were down, which is a good thing. But not sure on what may be the intent behind the resetting of the hosts file to hosts.ac every time...

See the following link, and specially the superuser link listed there:

http://jeffreybarke.net/2012/02/anyconnect-reverts-hosts-file/

Comment: I have heard about `hosts.ac`, and I do not understand the rationale, either. Perhaps Cisco wants to control your `hosts` file. What does the comment mean, though, when it doesn't want you to change the file until you delete the comment? Is it just a precaution?

Comment: I read somewhere you could just make a symbolic link from `hosts` to `hosts.ac`. I'm planning on doing that.

Comment: When I read the comment I thought that AC modified the hosts file *only while the VPN session was up*, hence the message. But from what I have read from others, it does not pull the changes back after the VPN session is down, so I'm not sure exactly on what they mean by that comment...

Comment: Yeah, I don't know. It might just be Cisco being paranoid. I created 2 copies of my `hosts` file, one in the same folder, the other in My Documents, so if it gets overwritten I'll be OK.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should accept this. It does not technically answer my question, but it's probably the best almost anyone outside Cisco will do. On the other hand, if I accept now, and someone who could answer it definitively goes searching, they may not find my question or think it's closed, etc.

Comment: I mean I'm not sure if I should accept this answer. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: I think `hosts.ac` is still affecting my `hosts` file even though I made a symlink from `hosts.ac` to `hosts`. I think I'm just going to delete my school's VPN and maybe reinstall it when they get their act together.

Comment: Sorry @James, I just realized this answer answers my question as asked. I was having another problem with AnyConnect and I'm kind of oblivious. Accept my long-overdue acceptance of your answer!

Answer (score 2):

I am working a TAC case with Cisco and the expected behavior is that the entry in the host file should be removed as soon as the Anyconnect client makes a valid connection to the ASA.  The host.ac file is just a placeholder for the original host file until connection is established then is deleted.

You will notice that the normal host file timestamp will update to reflect this behavior.

In our case, the host file does not revert back to original once connection has been established.  The timestamp reflects this.  The host.ac file is deleted.

Comment: I can't really test this anymore, as I uninstalled my AnyConnect and don't want to deal with it again (until I have to download something from my school's website again, but then hopefully they'll *finally* update it).